# Angular material autocomplete demo

Tags: autocomplete, angular-material

Can someone explain the following code in Angular material documentation autocomplete basic usage demo https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

```
function createFilterFor(query) {
  var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

  return function filterFn(state) {
    return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

CreateFilterFor() function just converts your input/query to lowercase format. filterFn() function checks(true/false) whether the state array/object contains a value corresponding to the query/input string.